# Inserting multiple types in map in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Is it possible in cassandra map to input different data types like if I have a table like

```
(id int, value map<text,text>)
```

Now I want to insert values in this table like

```
(1,{'test':'test1'})
(2,{'a':1})
(3,{'c':2})
```

Answer (score 8):

The Cassandra `Map` type does not support values (or keys) of differing types.  However, you could create a [User Defined Type](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html) to handle that.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> CREATE TYPE testac (test text, a int, c int);

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> CREATE TABLE testactable (
                                    key int, 
                                    values frozen<testac>,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (key));

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO testactable (key,values) 
                              VALUES (1,{test: 'test1', a: 1, c: 2});

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROm testactable ;

 key | values
-----+-----------------------------
   1 | {test: 'test1', a: 1, c: 2}

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I know this, and this will not solve my problem at hand. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having map in you case have it as text (String) column which will save you lots of space.  Keep data in JSON format by stringifying it.

Answer (score 0):

No Cassandra does not support like this feature .cassandra Map is like java map and we know that java also does not support this . we have pass all value in map according to datatype .

Comment: Except Java has inheritance and you can have a value type of `Object`.